# Convert from big Endian to Hex String with java

Tags: java, hex, endianness

How can I convert from 16-bit unsigned integer big Endian to Hex String? I want to make the inverse of what you can see in the screenshot.
[image]

From the Big Endian value `13089` I want to have as a result `3321`. I tried this but I got as result `71 48 97 92` which is a totally different value that expected

```
Integer.reverseBytes(value);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray() reverse the order of the bytes, but exclude the last (highest) if it is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(13089);
System.out.println(hex) //prints 3321
```

You don't have to reverse bytes because its already a big-endian representation.